# EasyTabs if statement, "if (tab.is())"

Tags: jquery

I have a google map loading within a hidden tab. I have fixed the resize issue and working perfectly. However. I was reading through the Steve Schwartz's blog and he mentioned that it's possible to have this resize event occur only once, as a way of limiting api requests (this has also been mentioned here on Stackoverflow). so a post from 2001 by Steve suggested using the following:

```
var googleMapsInit = false;
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#tab-container')
    .easytabs()
    .bind('easytabs:after', function(evt, tab) {
      if ( tab.is('#tab3') && !googleMapsInit) {
        google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
        map.setCenter(myLatlng);
        googleMapsInit = true;
      }
    });
});
```

I have tried this, but `if ( tab.is('#tab3') && !googleMapsInit) {` isn't being recognised. I have tried replacing this line with:

```
 if (($tab == '#tab3') && !googleMapsInit) {
```

But this isn't working either. Does anyone, with knowledge of EasyTabs, know how I can construct this if statement, so that if the hidden tab is selected and GoogleMapsInit is false, the resize event is called?

I have tried to look through the .js file for EasyTabs for clues. I have replaced `$tab` with `$selectedTab` with no luck either :-(

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that `#tab3` is a href value, like in EasyTabs sample. Then you could do like this:

```
var googleMapsInit = false;
$('#tab-container').easytabs().bind('easytabs:after', function(evt, tab) {
      if ( tab.is('[href="#tab3"]') && !googleMapsInit) {
          google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
          map.setCenter(myLatlng);
          googleMapsInit = true;
      }
});
```

I.e. use `href` in selector. See [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/a5L6j6d0/1/). If it's not the case, then post your markup, so I could update the answer.